# Checking the user input in perl for characters and length

Tags: regex, perl, unix, scripting

My question is basically as the title says. 
How can I check, in perl, whether a user inputted string

1. is only certain characters long (for example, 3 characters long)
2. contains only characters (for example, it should only contain the characters 'u', 'a', 'g', and 'c')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my $input = <>;
if ($input =~ /^[uagc]{3}$/g){
    # your codes
} else {
    #exit or die;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$s =~ /^[uagc]{3}\z/
   or die("usage\n");
```